# About a map from a finite set to itself.

Tags: functions

> Show $f(x)=a_i \cdot x$ is an injection, then since it's a map from a finite set to itself that implies it's also a surjection.

For $1, 2, 3$ values of $f(x)$ are in $\{a_i, a_i \cdot 2, a_i \cdot 3\}$. So, $f$ maps $\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$ to $\{a_i, a_i \cdot 2, a_i \cdot 3, ..., a_i \cdot n\}$. Is that correct? If so, how do we know $f$ maps from finite set to itself?

edit: Let $a_i \cdot x = a_i \cdot y.$ Then, $x = y.$ But I'd like to understand what the deal is with the function $f$ which maps a set to itself.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f : A \to A$ is an injective function with $A$ a finite set with $n$ elements.

Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $f$ is not surjective, then there exists at least one element in the codomain that doesn't get mapped to by $f$. By the pigeonhole principle, since we have $n$ elements and only $n - 1$ places to map them to, at least two must map to the same element, contradicting that $f$ is injective. Conclude that $f$ must be surjective.